# Stubborn Redux action sends empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've got this chunk of code:

```
        const result = Object.keys(state).reduce((result, key) => {
        if (key.includes('game')) {
          result[key] = state[key];
        }
        return result;
      }, []);
      this.props.sendBackResult(result);
```

The last line of course fires Redux action. But this instead of sending nicely formatted array sends only empty array. What is the reason of that?
When I'm inserting a log it out instead of sending the action I see proper result of previous function.

Thanks!

Comment: Your initial value of the `reduce` is an empty array, but you iterate over all the keys in your state? Shouldn't you use an empty object as initial value? What is it that you want to send to `sendBackResult`?

Comment: The best would be to send an array

Comment: How do you want that array to look? Setting a key with `result[key]` is most fitting for an object.

Comment: This format would be the best for me: [game00: Array(1), game01: Array(1)]

Comment: Alright. You can't have keys in an array like that. Are you sure you don't want an object where every key has an array as value? I.e. `{ game00: [ ... ], game01: [ ... ] }`

Comment: if you absolutely need an array change `result[key] = state[key];` to `result.push(state[key]);` otherwise change `result` into an object instead of an array and keep your code as-is.

Comment: All right guys, thank you for your help :) object will be fine here as well, just different approach later on. And thank you for helping me second time @Tholle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an empty array `[]` as initial value for your `reduce`. Setting a key on the array is most likely not something you want to do.

You could instead push the values all the keys that have `game` in them correspond to to the array:

```
const result = Object.keys(state).reduce((result, key) => {
  if (key.includes('game')) {
    result.push(state[key]);
  }
  return result;
}, []);
```

If you still want the keys in your final result, you most likely want to use an object instead:

```
const result = Object.keys(state).reduce((result, key) => {
  if (key.includes('game')) {
    result[key] = state[key];
  }
  return result;
}, {});
```